# Join on subquery Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

need help translating MySQL to zf2 TableGateway SQL

Mysql Query:

```
select t1.* from response t1
inner join 
(select activity_id, max(submitted) as recent from response where learner_id = '<USER_ID>' group by activity_id) t2
on t1.activity_id = t2.activity_id
where t1.submitted = t2.recent
order by activity_id;
```

ZF2 Query I came up with:

```
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($learnerId)
    {
        $inner = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select (array('t2'=>'response'));
         $inner ->columns(array('activity_id'),array('recent' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("max(submitted)")))
                ->where('learner_id ?', $learnerId)
                ->group('activity_id');      

$select
         ->join(array('t1' => $inner),
                     't1.activity_id = t2.activity_id')
         ->where('submitted = submitted')
         ->order('activity_id');
    });
```

Error:

> Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column 't2.activity_id' in 'on clause')

Comment: what is the problem with this query ? what happens ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: I get a error from zend saying `Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column 't2.activity_id' in 'on clause')`.

Comment: The problem doesn't concerns join in your subquery then. Are you sure your table response does have the column `activity_id` ?

Comment: yes. I'm pretty sure the error is regarding the alias (t2). For some reason it's not allowing me to alias the table. When i execute raw SQL I'm getting the expected results. But I'm getting an error when I run the Zend query.